# Is there a statistical analysis test I can perform that will give me a estimate of total population from my own smaller data sets?

Tags: zoology, ecology, statistics

Doing my dissertation on the long term trends in moth populations. I am looking at the trends of specific species. Is there a method to obtain an estimate of total population from smaller samples?

Comment: Do you mean estimate of population size? From what kind of samples? Do you have genetic data? do you have capture-recapture data, ...?

Comment: The point of a statistical test is not give you an estimate, it is to test a null hypothesis.

Comment: @Remi.b I disagree with the statement that statistical tests are used only to test null hypotheses. Statistical tests can be used to estimate population parameters, of which population size is one.

Comment: @kmm IMO, one might use the statistic that the test returns when you use a given package, but per say, a test means that you want to "test" a hypothesis for the sake of testing it. If the OP is trying to estimate a parameter, (s)he does not need to make any test. If (s)he has a hypothesis he wants to test (like *the population size is equal to 2000*), then (s)he needs a test. Asking "Was statistical test estimate this parameter?" sounds wrong to me (it should either be "How to estimate this parameter?" or "How to test to the null that the parameter is 2000?").

Comment: Why is this "too broad"? This is a very specific question on which there is a large and relevant literature. Just because you're not familiar with the topic doesn't mean it's off topic.

Comment: @iayork I agree, this should be reopened. The Q could show more effort and background, but I dont find it too broad.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you're asking how to estimate population size based on numbers of individuals you capture. Yes, there are many approaches to this. The R library [SPECIES-R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPECIES/SPECIES.pdf) offers a number of methods of calculating this. They are described in the manuscript [SPECIES: An R Package for Species Richness Estimation](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i09). Some of the methods described are:

- Chao, A. (1984), Nonparametric Estimation of the Number of Classes in a Population, Scandinavian Journal of Statistics, 11, 265-270.
- Norris, J. L. I., and Pollock, K. H.(1998), Non-Parametric MLE for Poisson Species Abundance Models Allowing for Heterogeneity Between Species, Environmental and Ecological Statistics, 5, 391-402.
- Chao, A., and Bunge, J. (2002), Estimating the Number of Species in a Stochastic Abundance Model, Biometrics, 58, 531-539.

and many more.

Comment: ±1 for your well referenced answer. My motto still is that a good answer can make the question. Perhaps you could add a little background in the question post.